# Using Swift struct Constructor as Function

Tags: function, swift, struct, constructor

Given a `struct S` defined in this way

```
struct S {
    let a : String 
    let b : Int 
    let c : Bool 
}
```

and a function `sConstructorFun`

```
func sConstructorFun(#a:String, #b:Int, #c:Bool) -> S { 
    return S(a:a, b:b, c:c) 
}
```

I can use both `sConstructorFun(a:"", b:1, c:false)` and `S(a:"", b:1, c:false)` to get the following `S` value (as the REPL outputs it)

```
S = {
  a = ""
  b = 1
  c = false
}
```

So `S` and `sConstructorFun` have the very same interface and unsurprisingly return the same result.

However, a `sFactory` function defined as follows

```
func sFactory(f:(String, Int, Bool) -> S) -> S {
    return f("foo", 42, false) 
}
```

can only be used with the `sConstructorFun` but *not* with `S` directly:

```
REPL> sFactory(sConstructorFun) 
$R2: S = {
  a = "foo"
  b = 42
  c = false
}
```

and

```
REPL> sFactory(S) 
repl.swift:18:1: error: cannot invoke 'sFactory' with no arguments
sFactory(S)
^
repl.swift:18:9: note: expected an argument list of type '((String, Int, Bool) -> S)'
 sFactory(S)
         ^
```

Is there any way of using the default constructor of a `struct` (`S` in this example) as a function (without defining a new function/closure to do so)?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with `S = { a = "", b = 1, c = false }`. `S` is the struct, then you use `S` as a left value. The syntax does not appear to be a valid Swift construct

Comment: @MatteoPiombo that's how the REPL outputs structs: `
 18> S(a:"foo", b:1, c:false)
$R3: S = {
  a = "foo"
  b = 1
  c = false
}
`

Comment: SORRY! I cancelled a suggested edit, suggesting to change `func sConstructorFun(#a:String, #b:Int, #c:Bool) -> S` to `func sConstructorFun(a a:String, b b:Int, c c:Bool) -> S` because I thought that means something different. I'm really sorry about that and I will now reapply that edit.

Comment: posted as rdar://19849369 ||  http://openradar.appspot.com/19849369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the default constructor inside of a closure and pass that to the `sFactory` function. Try this:

```
let f = { S(a: $0, b: $1, c: $2) }

func sFactory(f:(String, Int, Bool) -> S) -> S {
    return f("foo", 42, false) 
}

let s = sFactory(f)

println("s = (a: \(s.a), b: \(s.b), c: \(s.c))") // S = (a: foo, b: 42, c: false)
```

Comment: that's defining a new function `f` which is to my `sConstructorFun` just without labelled arguments. It does save some typing though. Clarified the question.

Comment: Joe Groff, a Swift developer just [confirmed via Twitter](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/567388380548169729) that it's not possible at the moment and the easiest way is actually do define a new function wrapping the call :-(. I will therefore accept your answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you just use the letter `S`, Swift doesn't know what you want to do with it. You could be trying to pass the type as a parameter, or doing any number of other things with it. I'm curious, though, is that something that is common in other programming languages? Are there languages where you can pass the name of a type to a function and it will infer that you are trying to call a constructor? It would be kinda cool...

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear to me your intent, but maybe you are looking for constructors like these:

```
extension S {
    init (f: (a: String, b: Int, c: Bool) -> S) {
        self = f(a: "foo", b: 1, c: true)
    }

    init(f: () -> S) {
        self = f()
    }
}
```